# Python: migrate setup.py "scripts=" to entry_points

Tags: python, setup.py

I'd like to make use of someone else's python utility, *foobartools*, whose native environment is linux. *Foobartools* is pure python so there's no reason it can't be used on Windows, where I am.

In their `setup.py` they're using the older style `scripts=['bin/foobar'],`.

Running `pip install -e b:\code\foobar` creates a file called `foobar` in `%pythonhome%\Scripts`, but Windows doesn't know about it even though Scripts is in PATH. To use it I need to make a `@python %pythonhome%\scripts\foobar` batch file. This works but is non-optimal (*ctrl-c* handling is ugly for instance).

I know that if I add the newer and recommended [entry_points](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distributing.html#scripts) syntax to *setup.py* pip will automatically create `Scripts\foobar.exe` on Windows (and I can ditch the batch file). On Linux `Scripts\foobar` remains unchanged, and everybody is happy.

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': ['foobar = foobartools:main'],
}
```

I don't know what to do with the right hand side of the equation, `foobartools:main`. How do make that call `bin/foobar`? The *foobartools* module doesn't have a single callable function or module like that corresponds to the bin script, and the bin script is relatively complicated.

I want to make as few changes as possible to the project so that a) a patch submission has a better chance of getting accepted upstream, and b) if upstream remains uninterested there's less work for me to do to keep up with it.

*[update]* The existing source tree structure:

```
foobartools/
    bin/foobar
    foobartools/
        __init__.py
        foo/
            __init__.py
            one.py
            two.py
        bar/
            ...
        baz/
            ...
    setup.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I got to a working *Scripts\foobar.exe*, but it changes more of the code than I wish. I was hoping to get by with just a couple of tweaks to setup.py, or at least something that doesn't mess around inside upstream modules. I don't know it well enough to be sure I'm not getting in the way somehow.

(1) move `bin/foobar` --> `foobartools/foobar_cli.py`
(2) In setup.py, comment out `#scripts=...` and add:

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': ['foobar = foobartools.foobar_cli:main'],
}
```

*[later]* A refinement of the same core idea, means I keep my fat feet out of the main business area:

(1) move `./bin/foobar` --> `./foobar_cli/foobar.py` (note extension as well as folder change)
(2) add an empty `__init__.py` to same folder
(3) `console_scripts': ['foobar = foobar_cli.foorbar:main'],`

Comment: I think you came up with a very reasonable solution. `entry_points` only works for scripts which are encapsulated within a specific function in one of the included modules. I'm actually not sure why `setuptools` imposes such a limitation :-/