# Using console_scripts with more than one main() function

Tags: python, setup.py

How to build a console_scripts entry to script using multiple functions (not wrapped in a single main function), and you are not the author of the script?

For background read [Python: migrate setup.py "scripts=" to entry_points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518806/python-migrate-setup-py-scripts-to-entry-points). The answer in this previous question is successful when the script-to-be-called has all of its desirable operations in single starting function with no arguments, such as:

```
if '__name__' == '__main__':
    main_do_all()
```

and the setup.py entry is:

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': ['foobar = foobartools.foobar_cli:main_do_all'],
}
```

However it doesn't accommodate the script which uses multiple functions at the top level to do its thing:

```
if '__name__' == '__main__':
    prologue(sys.argv)
    do_thing()
    finish()
```

...because console_scripts can only name one function and can't use arguments (right?)

I've been thinking what is needed is to write a wrapper script with only one function - run the real script - and call that in setup.py. However reading up on exec(), execfile(), subprocess(), popen() it looks like a can of worms, and my early attempts with exec() fared poorly, making me doubt the approach.

For a test bed, the program-of-the-moment sparking this question is [mutagen](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen), though I've run into the situation other times.

What is the right way to do this?

---

### Test case and results

(In case of copy and paste errors, also see https://gist.github.com/maphew/865c02c9143fd954e5653a8ffb1fb441)

./my_cli/single_main.py:

```
# This works when 1st 3 functions are in the same file, but what to do when
# they're somewhere else, and meant to be called as a commandline script?

import sys

# --- copied from 'tools/multi_main' but we really want to run in-situ ---
def prologue(argv):
    print("Arguments recieved: {}".format(argv))

def do_thing():
    print("Doing something here")

def finish():
    print("All done now, cleaning up")
# --- end external ---

def main():
    prologue(sys.argv)
    do_thing()
    finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Running 'single_main' script")
    main()
```

./my_cli/cli.py:

```
# ./my_cli/cli.py
# wrapper created for console_scripts to run 'tools/multi_main'

import os
import sys

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

def multi_main(argv):
    fname = os.path.join(here, '../tools', 'multi_main.py')
    print(fname)
    with open(fname) as f:
        code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
        #exec(code, global_vars, local_vars)
        exec(code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multi_main(sys.argv)
```

./tools/multi_main:

```
# ./tools/multi_main
# This file from upstream source. We want to avoid editing.

import sys

def prologue(argv):
    print("Arguments recieved: {}".format(argv))

def do_thing():
    print("Doing something here")

def finish():
    print("All done now, cleaning up")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Running 'multi_main' script")
    prologue(sys.argv)
    do_thing()
    finish()
```

./setup.py:

```
#./setup.py

import os
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="multi_main",
    description="Migrating from scripts to console_scripts entry points",
    # Old, 'nix-only way
    scripts=[os.path.join("tools", name) for name in [
        "multi_main",
        ]],
    # new, multi-platform way (when get to working)
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_single_main = my_cli.single_main:main',
            'my_multi_main = my_cli.cli:multi_main',
            ],
        },
    )
```

---

Shell log:

```
[py34_x64] D:\b\code\console_script_multi
> pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///D:/b/code/console_script_multi
Installing collected packages: multi-main
  Running setup.py develop for multi-main
Successfully installed multi-main-0.0.0

[py34_x64] D:\b\code\console_script_multi
> my_single_main
Arguments recieved: ['C:\\Python34_x64\\Scripts\\my_single_main-script.py']
Doing something here
All done now, cleaning up

[py34_x64] D:\b\code\console_script_multi
> my_multi_main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34_x64\Scripts\my_multi_main-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('multi-main==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'my_multi_main')()
TypeError: multi_main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'argv'

[py34_x64] D:\b\code\console_script_multi
> multi_main
'multi_main' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[py34_x64] D:\b\code\console_script_multi
> python c:\Python34_x64\Scripts\multi_main
Running 'multi_main' script
Arguments recieved: ['c:\\Python34_x64\\Scripts\\multi_main']
Doing something here
All done now, cleaning up

[py34_x64] D:\b\code\console_script_multi
>
```

Comment: *"what is needed is to write a wrapper script with only one function"* - that is correct. Could you clarify how (and why!) you were using `exec` and what exactly *"fared poorly"* means?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm trying to avoid editing the script that does the real work. It's from an upstream source. Exec attempt at https://gist.github.com/maphew/865c02c9143fd954e5653a8ffb1fb441

Comment: Please put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, updated with test case